# Can you please identify these yellow dot parasites which grow on non-living surface?

Tags: species-identification

Little yellow dot parasites have screwed me for years and I still don't know how to fight back as I don't know what they are. I just know that they are living beings because they grow in number.

**Images:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sub>(Click the images to enlarge)</sub>

**Location:** North India

**Size:** Visible to naked eyes (one dot is approx 0.25 mm in diameter; their colony is upto 5 mm in length or diameter; their colonies aren't perfect circles as seen in the images)

**Behavior:** They grow on any plastic, metal and glass surfaces (but not on clothes, walls or wood) if they are stored in open (the surface is in contact with oxygen)

Can you please identify it?

Comment: _' I just know that they are living beings because they grow in number'_ How do they react when exposed to a biozide (Triclosan, Zink-Pyrithion etc..)?

Comment: @iLuvLogix Never tried.

Answer (score -2):

This looks like the work of an insect, perhaps a fly.
You can check by experimentation.

Try covering part of one surface with a fly-proof covering.
Take photos at weekly intervals of exactly the same area, compare images.

black-and-white images below from
Forensic Science International 137 (2003) 152–159
"Distinction of bloodstain patterns from fly artifacts"
Mark Beneckea, Larry Barksdale
DOI: 10.1016/j.forsciint.2003.07.012

Bar on images is 1cm

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you expand on the reasoning behind your conclusion?